# How to sum calculated fields coming from nested list

Tags: reportviewer

In a report I have 2 nested list and the last one has a table inside.
I can easily sum values in the table and have them in the total field.
Inside the nested list I do special calculation with table total value.
I would like to be able to sum all these calculated values in the outer list.

What I need is a way for the nested list to expose its results to the outer list and a way to aggregate them. I don't want and probably cannot do the calculation again in the outer list, I want to sum the results coming from the inner list.

It seems a simple task but I spent the entire morning surfing for a solution !!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes instead of clicking here and there for a more formal way of adding a solution to thing I many a times find that it could be done in a simple fashion also..

 
 what I mean by this that you can do like following

- Right Click tablix row and insert new row below
- Now at the cell where you want this aggregated sum total, you can simply use your existing expressions, that you are using in the previous cells, in this new cell where you want to display the results
   
  Something like this : 
  `=Sum(Fields!Total1.Value, "DATASET1") + Sum(Fields!Total2.Value, "DATASET2")`

See if it works for you, coz I always do like the same !